# BlobContainerClient from Azure SAS URI

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a POC to copy file from one azure storage account to another. What I have is SAS URI of source file and `SAS URI` of destination container. I trying to achieve this through Azure function app with `java`. What I tried `connectionString()` method of `BlobContainerClientBuilder` to connect to destination container but it threw error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection string.`

```
BlobContainerClient destinationBlobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(containerSasUri)
                .buildClient();


BlobClient destinationBlobClient = destinationBlobContainerClient.getBlobClient("newDirectory/test.txt");


SyncPoller<BlobCopyInfo, Void> poller = destinationBlobClient.beginCopy(data.getFileUrl(), Duration.ofSeconds(2));
poller.waitForCompletion();
```

I even tried `endpoint()` method of `BlobContainerClientBuilder` for instantiation of connection to destination container but that threw error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Date String: 2022-05-10.`

```
BlobContainerClient destinationBlobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(containerSasUri)
                .buildClient();
```

The destination SAS URI looks like this `https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/<contsin_name>?sv=2018-11-09&sr=c&st=2022-05-10&se=2025-05-09T16%1A66%3B09X&sp=racwdl&spr=https&rsct=application%2Foctet-stream&sig=%2Bba37rfqAeHCR%2BX8hU1yfqSgojB40`

After tryin to instantiate `BlobClient`, `BlonbServiceClient` and all failed with same errors, now I am wondering if instantiation using SAS URI is even possible or not, or I need service principal.

Comment: Does this help?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-java-stable#create-a-blobcontainerclient

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I created a container in my storage account and uploaded a **blob** like below,
[image]

Then, I created another container in my storage account and uploaded a **blob** as below,
[image]

When I download the **blob** from **firstcontainer** like below,
[image]

**Blob** looks like the below,

[image]

Then, I download **blob** from **secondcontainer** and it's look like below,
[image]

I followed the [Github-document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java.md?plain=1) with the same code can able to copy a **blob** from one container to another,

**Code:**

```java
String sourceSasUri = "sourceSASUri";
String destinationContainerSasUri = "destinationSASUri";
String destinationBlobName = "kam.txt";

BlobServiceClient sourceBlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(sourceSasUri)
                .buildClient();

BlobClient sourceBlobClient = new BlobClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(sourceSasUri)
                .blobName("type.txt")
                .buildClient();

BlobContainerClient destinationBlobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(destinationContainerSasUri)
                .buildClient();

BlobClient destinationBlobClient = destinationBlobContainerClient.getBlobClient(destinationBlobName);
SyncPoller<BlobCopyInfo, Void> poller = destinationBlobClient.beginCopy(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl(), Duration.ofSeconds(2));
        poller.waitForCompletion();
```

**SAS Uri** formate is as below,

```java
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storageaccountname>;AccountKey=<storageaccountkey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net/<containername>
```

**Output:**

It ran successfully as below,
[image]

Then, I downloaded the blob from **firstcontainer** and it's look like below,
[image]

And I downloaded the **blob** from **secondcontainer**, it's look like below,
It successfully copied the text from **blob** in **firstcontainer** shown as below,

[image]